# connection refused when I try to connect client with server

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I made a basic client / server **datasnap** applications and it work in local network through **http** but when I tried to connect from the internet I get connection refused, here are the steps I followed:

I set at the server component **TDSHTTPService** to connect through port no 8081 then in the client I set to use same port in **TSQLConnection** component, and I used my PC public IP in the HostName but when I try to connect I get connection refused.

Any advise ?

Forgot to say the client is Firemonkey app running on Android.

[image]

Comment: Do you have public IP? Are you behind a router / NAT? It is very likely that the problem is that your request does not even reach your computer because it is blocked in the middle.

Comment: @smooty86 yes, the server is behind a router running on windows 7 and the client is an Android app  , what I should do ?

Comment: You should go to router admin console, find something like "port forwarding" and route the port (8081) to your computer IP - you have to say the router that traffic on this port should go to your computer ;)

Comment: @smooty86 +1 yaaaay ..... that did it, many thanks, post it as an answer if u like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to router admin console, find something like "port forwarding" and route the port (8081) to your computer IP - you have to say the router that traffic on this port should go to your computer

Comment: Also called "Applications/Gaming" on home routers or "NAT Policies" on business routers.

Comment: @JerryDodge: in addition,  some home routers actually say "Port Forwarding", or "Virtual Server".

Comment: @Remy Yeah, I excluded "Port Forwarding" because smooty already mentioned it, but "Virtual Server" I've never heard used in this context.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Several routers that I have used at home have referred to "port forwarding" rules as "virtual servers".

Comment: @Remy Then again, I have worked tons more with business routers than home ones, and the few home routers I've had no need.